# How to obtain "integrity verdicts" from Firebase AppCheck?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-console, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api

I would like to add Firebase AppCheck to my mobile app to protect my backend (not Firebase services). I want to use Google Play Integrity provider (default one).

I know that Firebase AppCheck for Android is a wrapper around Google Play Integrity. It prepares "nonce" and calls`requestIntegrityToken` method to fetch "integrity verdicts". But these verdicts are not included in Firebase AppCheck Token which I pass to my custom backend. I read the source code of Firebase Android SDK and Firebase Admin SDK for NodeJS and I saw that Firebase Admin SDK uses https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/appcheck/rest/v1/projects.apps/exchangePlayIntegrityToken method to exchange "Google Play Integrity token" for Firebase AppCheck Token. And in that place we lost information about "integrity verdicts".

[image]

In Google Play Console there are given settings:
[image]

Why `MEETS_DEVICE_INTEGRITY` value cannot be deleted? How these values are considered by Firebase AppCheck? Let's say I checked all values in Google Play Console ("MEETS_STRONG_INTEGRITY", "MEETS_DEVICE_INTEGRITY", "MEETS_BASIC_INTEGRITY") and Google Play Integrity returns only one value: "MEETS_DEVICE_INTEGRITY". How Firebase AppCheck treats this verdicts? Is it valid or not? Does Firebase AppCheck return validated AppCheck Token or not?

Comment: Hey there, did you find any solution or workaround for this ?

Comment: Unfortunately not and I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I wrote my own process to call the PlayIntegrityAPI, but I would prefer to use Firebase App Check. I have to have the verdicts, though, in order to display useful messages. There can be issues with the check if the User needs to update Play Services.